# How to embed Facebook Page or timeline on a website on page scroll event using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, facebook, dom

I am trying to embed Facebook Page on a website, I am following `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin` I am able to embed the and normal case it works fine, but my requirement is a bit different The container which holds the facebook page is at the bottom of the webpage and **I want to load facebook page and its resources only if the user reaches to that facebook page container**, for That using page scroll event, I tried many ways so far my code is as below:-
Facebook Page Container div

```
<div class="col-12 col-xl-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12" id="facebook-container">
            
    <div id="fb-root"></div>

</div>
```

JQuery Code is as below

```
fbResource=true;
$(window).scroll(function() {     
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
if(fbResource){
   $.ajax({
                    url: "https://connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v7.0",
                    dataType: "script",
                    crossorigin: "anonymous",
                    //cache: true,
                    nonce: "JDoVHwlt",
                    success: function() {
                        $( "#facebook-container" ).append('<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" data-tabs="timeline" data-width="" data-height="" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/facebook" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebook">Facebook</a></blockquote></div>');
                    }
                });
            
           }

           fbResource=false;
}
           FB.XFBML.parse();

}
});
```

I have also tried with $getScript() jQuery function but no luck.
Please guide what am I doing wrong ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: _“Please guide what am I doing wrong ?”_ - for starters, you failed to give us an _actual_ problem description - “no luck” isn’t one. Please go read [ask]. What happened instead of what you expected? Did it not show at all? Did it still show to early? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: What is your `fbResource` supposed to be good for? You are toggling the value, but you don’t check what it contains anywhere. Right now, you would trigger a new AJAX request for the SDK each time the scroll event fires, and the scroll position is beyond the threshold. That is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: The page plugin also has an iframe version. You could just use that, then you don’t have to deal with loading of the JS SDK any more to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe No errors in colsole, embeded fb page does not load at all, fbResource variable is used to load the resources only one time,sorry I missed that condition if fbResource is true only then ajax  will be executed.

Comment: I would expect `FB.XFBML.parse();` to fail here, because the script is loaded asynchronously. If it doesn’t fail, meaning that object already exists at this point - then you probably already have the SDK loaded at this point already, from elsewhere. Either way, you are only adding the div element in the success handler of your AJAX function, so it would not be in the document already by the time you are calling the parse method.

Comment: I have moved the append part right after the fb-root div and placed `FB.XFBXML.paarse();` inside the success handler of AJAX. Still no errors on console and FB page does not load.

Comment: Have you checked whether it even enters the sucess handler?

Comment: Even if, this is probably still missing the proper SDK initialization. Appending “parameters” in the hash portion of the SDK URL works with the normal embed code and makes the SDK automatically initialize itself at this point - but I am not sure if that works the same way, when you AJAX the script into your document. Are you sure you don’t just want to use the iframe variant of the plugin instead …?

Comment: @CBroe Yes it enters into success handler, I have put some console.log message to check it. Unfortunately I can't go with the iframe. Is there any other alternative or work around, Please suggest.

Comment: Simply creating a script element with the appropriate attributes set and appending it to the document appears to work pretty flawlessly, https://jsfiddle.net/7w0f4xzd/